# Flask 400 bad request, "Failed to decode JSON object"; POST request

Tags: python, flask

I'm following a tutorial to learn to build an API with Flask. I got to the point where I'm defining the POST method, and I've done so here. However, whenever I go to post I'm hit with a 400 Bad Request error and a verbose message stating "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". I've tried submitting requests through both Postman and Insomnia and have been met with the same error each time. I've also tried with both .csv files (as the tutorial uses) and .json files (since that's where the error was coming from). My request looks like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users?locationId=5&name=Duane&city=Los%20Angeles`

```py
users_path = './data/users.json'

class Users(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('locationId', required=True, type=int)
        parser.add_argument('name', required=True, type=str)
        parser.add_argument('city', required=True, type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return {
            'loc': args['locationId'],
            'name': args['name'],
            'city': args['city']
        }, 200

api.add_resource(Users, '/users')
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip install werkzeug==2.0.2` fixed my case

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `jsonify` function provided by the `flask` library. Here's an example,

1. import jsonify function from flask library `from flask import jsonify`
2. replace `return` statement of your post function with this,

   `return jsonify(loc=args['locationId'], name=args['name'], city=args['city'])`

Comment: I've just gone in and implemented that and have been met with the same error, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

From the list of [changes in Werkzeug 2.1.0](https://Request.get_json()%20will%20raise%20a%20400%20BadRequest%20error%20if%20the%20Content-Type%20header%20is%20not%20application/json.):

> Request.get_json() will raise a 400 BadRequest error if the Content-Type header is not application/json.

This was the scenario where I was getting the errors.